# Binomial coefficients with sums

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is:

> Calculate:
> $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} { 3n \choose 3k }
>  $$

I tried something, with
$$2^n= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} { n \choose k }$$

But, have no idea how to get the correct solution which is:

$$ \frac{2(-1)^n+8^n}{3}$$

Comment: Please show more a bit of your effort!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sums of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940028/sums-of-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: I think the answer is just $8^n$

Comment: My biggest problem is how of: $  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} { 3n \choose 3k }
 $, get : $  \frac{2(-1)^n+8^n}{3}.
  $

Comment: @rash that's wrong

Comment: @C.F.G The configuration of the linked question is not the same as this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{3n}{3k}=\frac{8^n+2(-1)^n}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213583/show-that-sum-k-0n-binom3n3k-frac8n2-1n3)

Answer (score 4):

We know that $$(1+x)^{3n}=\sum_{r=0}^{3n}{3n \choose r}x^r$$

Put $x=1,\omega ,\omega^2$ and evaluate the sums as,
$$\begin{aligned}
(1+1)^{3n}&=\sum_{r=0}^{3n}{3n \choose r} \\ (1+\omega)^{3n}&=\sum_{r=0}^{3n}{3n \choose r}\omega^r \\ (1+\omega^2)^{3n}&=\sum_{r=0}^{3n}{3n \choose r}\omega^{2r}
\end{aligned}$$

Here $\omega$ is the cube root of unity.

Add all the equations, we get
$$2^{3n}+(1+\omega)^{3n}+(1+\omega^2)^{3n}=3\sum_{k=0}^n{3n \choose 3k}$$

Using the well known property of $$\omega^2+\omega+1=0 {\tag 1}$$ $$ \omega^3=1 {\tag 2}$$

Hence the required sum $\sum_{k=0}^n{3n \choose 3k}=\dfrac{2^{3n}+(1+\omega)^{3n}+(1+\omega^2)^{3n}}{3}$.

The RHS can be simplified by substituting (1), i.e.
$$\dfrac{2^{3n}+(-\omega^2)^{3n}+(-\omega)^{3n}}{3}$$ and using (2) we finally get

$$\frac{2(-1)^n+8^n}{3}$$

Comment: I have seen this trick many years ago in an IMO contest I think.

Comment: @C.F.G It's a typical workbook question for highschoolers in India.... :P

Comment: I did the same way. Thought about roots of unity. Can we extend this ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi What do you mean by extend? If you mean $$\sum_{k=0}^n {4n \choose 4k}$$ then yes, you can use the fourth root, and 5th roots for 5k etc...

Answer (score 2):

I think that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940028/sums-of-binomial-coefficients) is way too complicated for this problem.

So here is a hint:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}=2^{3n}=8^n$$

Moreover, observer that $$\sum_{k=0}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}=\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 0\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}+\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 1\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}+\sum_{k=0,k \equiv 2\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}$$

And another very useful thing is that $$\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 1\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}=\sum_{k=0,k \equiv 2\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}$$

So you have $$8^n=\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 0\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}+2\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 1\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}$$

Thus, if you prove that $$\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 1\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}=\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 0\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}+(-1)^n$$

You can substitute in $$8^n=\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 0\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}+2\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 1\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}$$

And you get what you want. Now lets prove

$$\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 1\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}=\sum_{k=0,k\equiv 0\pmod{3}}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}+(-1)^n$$

I hope this helped you. Try to prove this yourself, you can reach out in the comments section.

Comment: Well that was a nice race...I finished seconds later

Comment: Oh, thank you for telling me!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to generalise this as a result :

$\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom {\phi n}{\phi k} = \frac {1}{\phi} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{ \phi -1} \left ( 1 +  e^{\displaystyle  \frac {\iota 2k \pi}{\phi} } \right )^{\phi n} $

Also,

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{ \phi -1} \left ( 1 +  e^{\displaystyle  \frac {\iota 2k \pi}{\phi} } \right ) = \sum_{k=0}^{ \phi -1} \left ( 2\iota \sin \left ( \frac{k \pi }{\phi} \right )  \right )^{ \phi n} e^{ \iota k\cdot n\pi} $

Comment: Can you show the functioning for $\phi =3$ ? This looks nicely generalised, the final answer can be reached by some manipulations