# Find a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}4^k\binom{2n}{2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

We want to find a closed form expression for
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}4^k\binom{2n}{2k}$$
I've been trying to come up with some combinatoric approach to this problem. The number of ways to choose some $2k$ elements from a set of $2n$ elements is
$$\binom{2n}{2k}$$
but this is about as far as I can get. Any helpful identities or theorems/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you evaluated for small values of $n$? If yes, can you figure out what the pattern is? Did you at least try Wolfram?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sums of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940028/sums-of-binomial-coefficients)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{k\ge0} a_{2k} = \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}a_k.$$
Taking $$a_k=2^k \binom{2n}{k}$$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\ge0} 2^{2k}\binom{2n}{2k} 
&= \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} 2^k \binom{2n}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge0} 2^k \binom{2n}{k} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge0} (-2)^k \binom{2n}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1+2)^{2n} + \frac{1}{2}(1-2)^{2n} \\
&= \frac{9^n+1}{2}.
\end{align}
So
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{2k}\binom{2n}{2k} = \frac{9^n+1}{2} - 2^0\binom{2n}{0} = \frac{9^n-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $2^{2k}=4^k$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2+1)^{2n} &=&  \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} 2^{k} \\
(2-1)^{2n} &=& \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k \binom{2n}{k} 2^k.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: does binomial theorem not say that $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$? If so, where does the $\binom{2n}{2k}$ come from?

Comment: Try adding these equations together.

Comment: Check your summations: $$\sum_{k=0}^{2\cdot1}\binom{2\cdot1}{2k}2^k=\binom202^0+\binom222^1+\binom242^2=3\ne9=(2+1)^{2\cdot1}$$ Presumably you mean to add $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k2^k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2n}k2^k$.

Answer (score 1):

In a more general manner
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}x^k=-1+\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{2 n}+\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^{2
   n}\right)$$