# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2{n\choose k}^2=n^2 \binom {2n-2}{n-1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Please help me / give a hand with combinational prove for:
$$ 1^2 \binom  n 1 ^2 + 2^2 \binom n 2 ^2 + \dots + n^2 \binom n n ^2 = n^2 \binom {2n-2}{n-1}$$

Comment: Proofs of this form are often condusive to induction, especially since there are formulas to relate the pascal choose numbers to ones right before. Did you try this?  Might be less of a hammer than the complex integration below

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $B=\{n+1,\dots,2n\}$. LHS counts number of ways to chose two subsets of equal cardinality in $A$ and $B$ and then to choose a pair of elements - one from the subset of $A$ and other from the subset of $B$. This procedure counts all pairs from $A\times B$ with some multiplicity. Let's calculate it. Pair $(a,b)$ can be obtained from two subsets of cardinality $k$, which can be chosen $\binom{n-1}{k}^2$ ways, so this multiplicity is equal to $\binom{n-1}{0}^2+\dots+\binom{n-1}{n-1}^2$. It's well-known that this sum is equal to $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$. Since $|A\times B|=n^2$, LHS=RHS.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}z^k = nz(1+z)^{n-1}\tag{1}$$
hence, replacing $z$ with $e^{\pm i\theta}$ and using the Parseval identity:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k}^2&=&\frac{n^2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(1+e^{i\theta})^{n-1}(1+e^{-i\theta})^{n-1}\,d\theta\\&=&\frac{n^2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(2+2\cos\theta)^{n-1}d\theta\\&=&\frac{n^2 4^{n}}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-2}(\theta)\,d\theta\\&=&n^2\binom{2n-2}{n-1}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side can be simplified as follows
$$\sum_{m=1}^nm^2{n \choose m}^2=\sum_{m=1}^nm^2\frac{(n!)^2}{(m!)^2((n-m)!)^2}\\=\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{n^2((n-1)!)^2}{((m-1)!)^2((n-m)!)^2}\\=n^2\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose m-1}^2\right)\\=n^2\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}^2\right)}\\=n^2\color{blue}{{2n-2 \choose n-1}}$$
for the parts highlighted in blue we use the combinatorial identity from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients), (Equation $9$)
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}^2={2n \choose n}$$
which is derived from the Chu-Vandermode identity - this identity can be proved using a combinatorial argument, as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof).

Answer (score 0):

By  way of  enrichment here  is another  solution using  basic complex
variables.

Start by restating the problem using the alternate binomial coefficient:
we seek to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^2 {n\choose n-k}
= n^2 {2n-2\choose n-1}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$${n\choose n-k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n-k+1}} \; dz.$$

This gives the following integral for the sum:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^2 z^k \; dz.$$

Now recall that
$$(1+z)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} z^k$$
and hence
$$nz (1+z)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k z^k$$
and finally
$$z(n (1+z)^{n-1} + nz(n-1)(1+z)^{n-2})
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^2 z^k.$$

Substituting this into the sum gives
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\left(n \frac{(1+z)^{2n-1}}{z^n}
+ n(n-1) \frac{(1+z)^{2n-2}}{z^{n-1}} \right)\; dz.$$

Extracting coefficients we finally obtain
$$n {2n-1\choose n-1} + n(n-1) {2n-2\choose n-2}
\\= n \frac{2n-1}{n} {2n-2\choose n-1} 
+ n(n-1) \frac{n-1}{n} {2n-2\choose n-1}
\\ = (2n-1 + (n-1)^2) {2n-2\choose n-1}
= n^2 {2n-2\choose n-1}.$$

Apparently this method is due to Egorychev.
A trace as to when it appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).