# Prof Gould combinatorial identity 3.27 and its "cousin" formula

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In the book on Combinatorial Identities of Prof Gould I found the identity 3.27
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\rho}\binom{2x+1}{2k+1}\binom{x-k}{\rho-k}=\frac{2x+1}{2\rho+1}\binom{x+\rho}{2\rho}2^{2\rho}$$ 
I now cant handle its "cousin" formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\rho}\binom{2x+1}{2k}\binom{x-k}{\rho-k}=?$$ and am looking for a similar identity.

Maybe also the identity 3.26 is relevant or helpful in this context $$\sum_{k=0}^{\rho}\binom{2x}{2k}\binom{x-k}{\rho-k}=\frac{x}{x+\rho}\binom{x+\rho}{2\rho}2^{2\rho}$$ (Remark: to me looks this formula strangely different to 3.27 when I look at the denominator $x+\rho$)

Comment: @Visitors Prof Gould informed me that also the "cousin" formula is mentioned in his book under 3.149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$Q(x,\rho) = \sum_{k=0}^\rho {2x+1\choose 2k}
{x-k\choose \rho-k}$$

where $x\ge\rho.$

Introduce
$${x-k\choose \rho-k} = {x-k\choose x-\rho} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+z)^{x-k} \; dz.$$

Note that this controls the range being zero when $\rho\lt k \le x$ so
we can  extend the  sum to  $x$ supposing that  $x\gt \rho$.  And when
$x=\rho$ we may also set the upper limit to $x.$

We get for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+z)^{x} 
\sum_{k=0}^x {2x+1\choose 2k} \frac{1}{(1+z)^k}
\; dz.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+z)^{x} 
\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}\right)^{2x+1}
+ \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}\right)^{2x+1}\right) \; dz
\\ = 
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}
\left((1+\sqrt{1+z})^{2x+1}+(1-\sqrt{1+z})^{2x+1}\right) 
\; dz.$$

Observe that the second  term in the parenthesis (i.e. $1-\sqrt{1+z}$)
has no constant term and hence  starts at $z^{2x+1}$ making for a zero
contribution. This leaves

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}
(1+\sqrt{1+z})^{2x+1}
\; dz.$$

Now put $1+z=w^2$ so that $dz = 2w\; dw$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w^2-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
\frac{1}{w}
(1+w)^{2x+1}
\; w \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
\frac{1}{(w+1)^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+w)^{2x+1}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+w)^{x+\rho} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{x+\rho}
{x+\rho\choose q} 2^{x+\rho-q} (w-1)^q 
\; dw.$$

This is
$$[(w-1)^{x-\rho}]
\sum_{q=0}^{x+\rho}
{x+\rho\choose q} 2^{x+\rho-q} (w-1)^q 
\\= {x+\rho\choose x-\rho} 2^{x+\rho-(x-\rho)}
= {x+\rho\choose x-\rho} 2^{2\rho}
= {x+\rho\choose 2\rho} 2^{2\rho}.$$

Comment: This surmounts by far my capability in understanding the details of the steps of the proof. I used already the result in the proof of a theorem and get a correct result - at least for one test value. I think I refrain from posing any question as this would be intolerable for Marko.

Comment: Nice computation. I've never seen this sort of proof for binomial identities....

Comment: @user226970 I agree completely with your statement.

Comment: The two links included at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/) show an appearance of the method at MSE. Apparently this is known as the Egorychev method.

Comment: The step from your 4th to the 5th equation is not clear to me. I think in the 5th equation should be a minus sign before the second sum term. Also I think "Observe that the second term in the parenthesis (i.e. $1-\sqrt{1+z}$) has no constant term and hence starts at $z^{2x+1}$" should say it starts at $z^x$. I dont then understand how you argue with omitting the second term because of lack of my understanding the complex integral.

Comment: It seems correct to me. The positive sign is because we filter the even terms rather than the odd ones as in the other answer. (I suggest you compare the two answers.) Of course the power of the square root term refers to it being raised to the power $2x+1$ which looks correct as well.

Comment: Do you implicitly use the binomal expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ starting with $1$ in your reasoning ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\rho}\binom{2x+1}{2k}\binom{x-k}{\rho-k} = \binom{x+\rho}{2\rho}2^{2\rho}
$$
I did not try to prove it, but here is the reasoning: the term $ \binom{x+\rho}{2\rho}2^{2\rho} $ has to be there for asymptotic reasons. The fractional term in front I wasn't sure of, but I tried a few examples and it seems correct!

Comment: I will try this result in the proof of a theorem I work on and can then use the resulting formula to check whether I got the result of the theorem which I know already.

Answer (score 0):

We can also prove the companion identity from above.

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$Q(x,\rho) = \sum_{k=0}^\rho {2x+1\choose 2k+1}
{x-k\choose \rho-k}$$

where $x\ge\rho.$

Introduce
$${x-k\choose \rho-k} = {x-k\choose x-\rho} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+z)^{x-k} \; dz.$$

Note that this controls the range being zero when $\rho\lt k \le x$ so
we can  extend the  sum to  $x$ supposing that  $x\gt \rho$.  And when
$x=\rho$ we may also set the upper limit to $x.$

We get for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+z)^{x} 
\sum_{k=0}^x {2x+1\choose 2k+1} \frac{1}{(1+z)^k}
\; dz.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{x}}{z^{x-\rho+1}} \sqrt{1+z}
\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}\right)^{2x+1}
- \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}\right)^{2x+1}\right) \; dz
\\ = 
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
\left((1+\sqrt{1+z})^{2x+1}-(1-\sqrt{1+z})^{2x+1}\right) 
\; dz.$$

Observe that the second  term in the parenthesis (i.e. $1-\sqrt{1+z}$)
has no constant term and hence  starts at $z^{2x+1}$ making for a zero
contribution. This leaves

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+\sqrt{1+z})^{2x+1}
\; dz.$$

Now put $1+z=w^2$ so that $dz = 2w\; dw$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w^2-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+w)^{2x+1}
\; w \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
\frac{1}{(w+1)^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+w)^{2x+1}
\; w \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{x-\rho+1}}
(1+w)^{x+\rho} \; w \; dw.$$

Writing $w=(w-1)+1$ this produces two pieces, the first is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{x-\rho}}
\sum_{q=0}^{x+\rho}
{x+\rho\choose q} 2^{x+\rho-q} (w-1)^q 
\; dw.$$

This is
$$[(w-1)^{x-\rho-1}]
\sum_{q=0}^{x+\rho}
{x+\rho\choose q} 2^{x+\rho-q} (w-1)^q 
\\= {x+\rho\choose x-\rho-1} 2^{x+\rho-(x-\rho-1)}
= {x+\rho\choose x-\rho-1} 2^{2\rho+1}
= {x+\rho\choose 2\rho+1} 2^{2\rho+1}.$$

The second piece is
$$[(w-1)^{x-\rho}]
\sum_{q=0}^{x+\rho}
{x+\rho\choose q} 2^{x+\rho-q} (w-1)^q 
\\= {x+\rho\choose x-\rho} 2^{x+\rho-(x-\rho)}
= {x+\rho\choose x-\rho} 2^{2\rho}
= {x+\rho\choose 2\rho} 2^{2\rho}.$$

Joining the two pieces we finally obtain
$$\left(2\times \frac{x-\rho}{2\rho+1} + 1\right)
\times {x+\rho\choose 2\rho} 2^{2\rho}
\\ = \frac{2x+1}{2\rho +1}
{x+\rho\choose 2\rho} 2^{2\rho}.$$